# Javascript notifications to Flex on Multiple objects

Tags: javascript, apache-flex

I know that with ExternalInterface, we can register ActionScript functions that will be callable from JavaScript, But i want to register actionscript function for of one class which has multiple instance created in the Application. So how it will recognize which object action script  function will called from java script.

For example :

1) Java script : Has function javaScripAlert() which call Action script function  showAlert();

Ie    testSwf.alert(value);

function javaScripAlert (value) {

```
    TestSwf.alert();
```

}

2) Class ABC  has call back function  showAlert (value); It register callback function “showAlert” in class ..

Ie . ExternalInterface. addCallback(“alert”, showAlert);

3) TestApplication  : in this I have created multiple objects of Calss ABC

Ie

I have created multiple object of type ABC in the TestApplication  . so when I call javaScript function  javaScripAlert() from HTML  it  only calls function showAlert (value)  of  object  “abc3” and not for the other objects abc1 ,abc2.

So is any way that function of other object also called at that time .

Thanks & Regards,
Sanjay Ruparelia

Answer (score 0):

Each Actionscript object that calls `ExternalInterface.addCallback("myCallback", myCallback)` will override the javascript callback.  So the last Actionscript object to call that wins.

**Example**:

**TestObject.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="400" height="300"
    initialize="registerCallback()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

            protected function registerCallback():void
            {
                if (ExternalInterface.available)
                {
                    ExternalInterface.addCallback("myCallback", myCallback);
                }
            }

            protected function myCallback():void
            {
                trace(this);
            }

            protected function callJavascript():void
            {
                ExternalInterface.call("myCallback");
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Panel width="100%" height="100%" click="callJavascript()"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

**Javascript in HTML**

```
function myCallback()
{
    getFlashContent().myCallback();
}
function getFlashContent()
{
    return document.getElementById("MyApp");
}
```

**Sample App**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:local="*">

    <mx:Panel id="panel" width="100%" height="100%" >
        <local:TestObject width="100%" height="50"/>
        <local:TestObject width="100%" height="50"/>
        <local:TestObject width="100%" height="50"/>
    </mx:Panel>

</mx:Application>
```

**Output** (when clicking)

```
MyApp.panel.TestObject34
MyApp.panel.TestObject34
MyApp.panel.TestObject34
```

A workaround would be to have all of those `ExternalInterface.addCallback("myCallback", myCallback);` calls in a Manager/Util class (some singleton-like thing).  Then make sure you only add it once.  Then you can pass individual items into the method.

Lance

Comment: Thank you very much , 
It helps a lot 
Sanjay